# Apache Geode servers ocassionally run out of connections during load tests

Tags: java, geode

Good afternoon,

We are trying to migrate application from Redis to Geode cluster for better scalability and Multi-WAN synchronization.
Currently we are testing one cluster only. Set up is:

- 8 hardware servers (64 cores CPU, 256GB RAM, Debian Linux v9 Stretch)
- 16 Geode servers, 2 per hardware host (v1.10.0). We tested with JDK8 and CMSGC, but decided to upgrade to OpenJDK13 and ShenandoahGC for low pauses, as it supposed to be a super fast cache

Server settings:

```
--max-connections=1200 --J=-Xmx12G --J=-Xms12G --J=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
--J=-XX:+UseShenandoahGC --J=-XX:+DisableExplicitGC --J=-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
--J=-Xlog:gc*:file=gc-%p-%t.log:uptime,time:filecount=3,filesize=10m --J=-Dgemfire.conserve-sockets=false
```

- 4 locators
- 5 regions:

  - 4 PARTITION_REDUNDANT with redundant-copies 1 (with different entry-time-to-live-expiration-s from 1hr to 7 days and entry-time-to-live-expiration-action destroy)
  - 1 REPLICATE with entry-time-to-live-expiration 7 days

During load tests we intermittently (once an hour) face this error in server logs:

```
[info 2019/11/18 16:46:03.561 PST <Pooled Waiting Message Processor 20> tid=0x925b] ...
[warn 2019/11/18 17:30:46.363 PST <Handshaker /XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:10001 Thread 152> tid=0xaed1] Rejected connection from /XX.XXX.XXX.XXX because current connection count of 1200 is greater than or equal to the configured max of 1200
[warn 2019/11/18 17:30:46.363 PST <Handshaker /XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:10001 Thread 155> tid=0xb503] Rejected connection from /XX.XXX.XXX.XXX because current connection count of 1200 is greater than or equal to the configured max of 1200
...[hundreds of these messages]
```

on clients:

```
org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerRefusedConnectionException: servername(servername:28165)<v145>:41001 refused connection: exceeded max-connections 1200
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Handshake.readMessage(Handshake.java:331)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ClientSideHandshakeImpl.handshakeWithServer(ClientSideHandshakeImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ConnectionImpl.connect(ConnectionImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ConnectionConnector.connectClientToServer(ConnectionConnector.java:71)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createClientToServerConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.pooling.ConnectionManagerImpl.createPooledConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.pooling.ConnectionManagerImpl.forceCreateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:212)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.pooling.ConnectionManagerImpl.borrowConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.pooling.ConnectionManagerImpl.borrowConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:70)
```

Client code:

```
        ClientCacheFactory cacheFactory = new ClientCacheFactory()
                .set("log-level", "ERROR");
        for (String locator : locators) {
            HostPort hostPort = new HostPort(locator);
            cacheFactory.addPoolLocator(hostPort.getHost(), hostPort.getPort());
        }
        this.cache = cacheFactory.create();
```

and then

```
    private <K,V> Region<K, V> getOrCreateRegion(String name, ClientRegionFactory<K, V> regionFactory) {
        Region<K, V> region = cache.getRegion(name);
        if (region == null) {
            region = regionFactory.create(name);
        }
        return region;
    }
```

to get region, no custom options are set.

Normal amount of client connections on each server is around 250, but at some random time during load test (60k read RPS / 60k write RPS)
amount of connections jumps up to maximum (1200) and clients can not open connection.
Partitioned regions have scope "distributed-ack" which results in huge spike of errors and data corruption.
Server self-heals in a minute or two and number of connections drops to normal, but by that time test is failed.
I tried increasing log level, but "INFO" just shows nothing (checked affected server and locator logs), "DEBUG" generates so much data, that servers can not keep up with flood of log messages.
120k read+write RPS is normal production traffic for us, testing with 10k overall RPS did not cause exceptions. These lock ups are not connected with garbage collection, as gc logs show no gc running during that time

Do you have any ideas how to tune Geode cluster to avoid these exceptions and data corruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "refused connection: exceeded max-connections" error happens because the clients are trying to create more connections to the servers than the max-connections that you set.

The clients use a connection pool, so the number of concurrent connections from a single client is proportional to the number of threads that are currently doing operations from the client.

The next step is to figure out how many threads your load generation is actually creating. Theoretically, each thread should only be using a single connection at a time, so worst case for max-connections should be around num_threads * num_clients if the load is very uneven and all of the clients are targeting the same server at the same time.

If you are unable to control the number of threads on the client, the pool itself has tuning parameters such as PoolFactory.setMaxConnections which will limit the number of connections from a single client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for idea Dan. Clients which connect to Geode are web applications, thus amount of threads are mostly limited by Jetty connection pool, but some workflows might use multiple threads. I will play with client pool settings.